# Deleting a file on hard by R

Tags: r, unlink

When I use the function "unlink()", the file is deleted from my eyes but still the capacity of the drive remains as the same as the past till I close the R. In the run of my program I need some free space on drive but with "unlink" function just the file is disappeared from my eyes and the capacity of the drive is not changed till closing R. Any idea....

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a shell command deleting the file instead.

```
shell('rm path/to/file.fl')
```

Answer (score 0):

R has a number of functions from manipulating files from R level:

```
file.create(..., showWarnings = TRUE)
file.exists(...)
file.remove(...)
file.rename(from, to)
file.append(file1, file2)
file.copy(from, to, overwrite = recursive, recursive = FALSE,
          copy.mode = TRUE, copy.date = FALSE)
file.symlink(from, to)
file.link(from, to)
```

among those functions `file.remove(...)` function that deletes files, can be found. See `?files` to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

While you may try to use different delete function(s), that might not be a true solution - you won't get disk space back.

Basically, file metadata has reference counter. If file is in one directory, ref.counter is one. If file is linked to two directories, ref.counter is two. If file is opened by some program (R, for example), ref.counter is bumped by one. When you close file, ref.counter is reduced by one.

Only when ref.counter is set to 0, OS/filesystem is free to reclaim file data and get disk space back.

Moral of the story: you might want to unlink/delete file, but also close file from inside R. Using connections might better serve your needs, https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html. Just open file connection, read from it, close it and explicitely set connection to NULL